# Log file has thousands of entries but wallet is empty?

Tags: wallet-recovery, logging

I know I tried mining BTC several years ago and found a backup from that machine. The debug.log has several thousand entries but yet the wallet.dat in the same folder shows up 0 transactions and is empty according to BTC core. I guess this could be some other BTC installation I had but does it make sense for the log file to have that many entries yet the wallet.dat is empty?

Answer (score 1):

> *does it make sense for the log file to have that many entries yet the wallet.dat is empty?*

Yes,

The logfile just shows the wallet checking its datafiles, communicating with other nodes, collecting blockchain data etc.

Even if you never send or receive money, the log file will have a record of lots of activity.

---

Related

- [How can I tell when bitcoind has found a block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17985/13866)

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything I could look for in the debug.log that would indicate mining actually happened?

Comment: See [How can I tell when bitcoind has found a block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17985/13866)